# Java- Use void method to change the state from closed to open by changing the value of the boolean

Tags: java, boolean, void, boolean-logic

Java-
Use void method to change the state from closed to open by changing the value of the boolean

public class name
open = false

———————————————————————-

public void open(){

}

This is how the answer should be look like with something inside .what should i write in it? Thank youu

Comment: At least put some effort into your homework. We're not here to do it for you and enough teachers would (rightly) treat this a cheating.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic Java getter/setter class.  You create a constructor to set initial values.  For each value, you create a getter and a setter.

Here's the class structure.

```
public class Status {
    
    private boolean open;
    
    public Status() {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(boolean open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

}
```